# Installing dependencies -Installing node modules - npm ERR! Cannot read property 'axios' of undefined

Tags: node.js, deployment, axios, undefined, npm-package

I'm facing an issue while deploying my Node.js application to Heroku. I have followed the troubleshooting steps provided in the documentation, but the error persists, preventing the successful deployment of my application.

Here is the error message I encountered during the deployment process:

```
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! Cannot read property 'axios' of undefined
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.txzIw/_logs/2023-05-26T17_33_46_596Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

I have already ensured that the 'axios' package is correctly declared as a dependency in my package.json file. Locally, the application runs without any issues. I have also cleared the npm cache, reinstalled dependencies, and double-checked for circular dependencies.

I have reviewed the provided debug log file (/tmp/npmcache.txzIw/_logs/2023-05-26T17_33_46_596Z-debug.log), but it does not offer additional insights into the root cause of the problem.

Please let me know if there are any specific configurations or steps that I might have missed or if there are any alternative solutions that I could explore.

Comment: We're not heroku or any other support team. This is a forum of volunteers. Also, you were not writing an email, but a question to this forum. Also, please don't post same text multiple times.